# Facebook online_presence always says Offline

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've created an android app with Facebook 3.0 sdk. I'm trying to fetch all the friends who are online using FQL. I'm using the below FQL query with the following Permissions added under App>App Details>App Center listed platforms>Configure App centre permissions -

Permissions:`user_status, user_online_presence, friends_online_presence`

FQL query:

```
SELECT name, online_presence FROM user where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

However, online_presence is always displaying 'offline' for all the friends even though few among them are online.

Output:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "name": "My Name",
        "online_presence": "active"
    }
]
```

}

Please someone help me if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

If you query the user table then you're going to get the results for **all** of your friends. If you have a lot of friends then likely most of them will be offline, making it look like all the user's are reported as being offline.

If you adjust your query to show only people who are **not** offline, you should hopefully get some results:

```
SELECT name, online_presence FROM user 
where uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) 
AND online_presence != "offline"
```

Remember that users can control if their friends' applications can see them as being online in the "Apps others use" section of the [apps settings page](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications&section=friends_share&view). So some of your friends may show as online in the Facebook website interface, but not online when your app queries the API.

[image]